# Create a text file with batch with a specific path

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, cmd

Hello im trying create a .txt file in an other folder then the batch file. But it just won't work and i dont know what i am doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
echo %Time% / %Date% / %pass% >> C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\My Progrmms\Log.txt
```

Comment: Path should be surrounded by quotes like this: "c:\...\etc". Note that there are folders with spaces in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
echo %Time% / %Date% / %pass% > "C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\My Progrmms\Log.txt"
```

Comment: @LightflashLP ... and don't forget to delete the file `C:\Users\Sebastian\Documents\My.`